# Laravel make mulitselect array result into string

Tags: php, laravel

I have one problem that I can't solve:

I have a form with a lot inputs. To keep the request clean I have sorted the input names with arrays. Everything works as expected. The only problem is I can't access the values of a multiselect input.

My input field:

```
<select multiple name="company[jobs][]">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Beschäftigte Berufe</option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
</select>
```

And I try to convert this into a string (each option seperated with a `;`) with this php code (it is a function, but that doesn't matter here). This code is placed inside the `company` model and I call the method with `$company->shortEdit($request->company);`.

The method head looks like this:

```
public function shortEdit($request) {

    $jobs = "";
    foreach($request->jobs as $job) {
        $jobs = $jobs . ";" . $job;
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

> Trying to get property 'jobs' of non-object

How can I fix this? The code works perfectly fine if my select isn't a multidimensional array.

*And yes, I dumped the request and the array `company[jobs]` isn't empty.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` of your input is `company` so the correct way is

```
$request->company['jobs'];
```

Comment: Do you know how I can split the request? That I can use functions like `->has()` on the array?

Comment: i do not know what you need to do , but if you need to check if value found in array you can use in_array()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function shortEdit($request) {

    $jobs = "";
    foreach($request->input('company.jobs') as $job) {
        $jobs = $jobs . ";" . $job;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Additionally, do you think that this is a good solution? Why not use something like `implode`?